# What is the word for 'slow change of direction'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

While combing through an article I was proofreading, I came to a sentence:

"I slowly swerved towards Computer Science."

The sentiment that the sentence tries to convey is of a slow change towards computer science, but swerve means, according to the dictionary, a sudden/abrupt change in direction. Can anyone suggest a single word for a slow change in direction?

Comment: @Elasthiccgirl: OP needs a single word.

Comment: I think **shift** would work

Comment: "[gravitated towards](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravitate)"

Comment: Please be clear, "proofreading" is solely about whether the final, printed version matches the original text… ie, spelling and nothing else; never.
You're correct in that "slowly swerved' is contradictory but that’s nothing to do with “proofreading”.
If you’re looking at editing, what makes you think "slowly" is correct and "swerved” wrong, please?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin I've just checked the normative definitions of 'proofread' in six  reputable dictionaries. Your definition is offered in none of them. If it _is_ a valid definition, it's domain-specific and needs flagging as such; OP is quite correct in using 'proofreading' as a synonym for 'looking [in texts] for items needing correction' here.

Comment: @Phil Sweet. I think  you should add that as an answer (even if the comment is over a year old). It's the most accurate imo.

Comment: Edwin, it's a side issue and still I worked "in the print" for nearly 20 years, for dozens of publishers of hundreds of titles, all of whom would tell you proof-reading is about little but typographical accuracy.

Proof-readers might raise queries like 2+2=6 but to be trite, how would questioning wider issues allow anyone to publish anything deviating from fact? How could I publish a story about Britain winning the failed US Rebellion of 1775-8, or Nazi Germany winning WWII?

The Question is clearly about editing and it is no business of a proof-reader to question vocabulary in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **veer**, hence:

> I slowly veered towards Computer Science

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/veer) defines this as:

> to change direction or turn about or aside; shift, turn, or change from one course, position, inclination, etc., to another

This definition does not indicate whether that change is rapid or slow.

Although other dictionaries such as [OxfordDictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/veer) do indicate that the change of direction is sudden:

> Change direction suddenly

personally I disagree with this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

‘Meander’ and ‘drift’ came to mind, though I feel they both imply a certain level of sluggishness or aimlessness without a clarifying adverb.

Comment: Yeah, they seem to imply a certain degree of aimlessness.

Answer (score 0):

When I studied the locomotion of the insect "catterpillar", I found it unique than rest of the animal's locomotions.

Catterpillars usually crawl.
[Merriam Webster](http://iam-webster.com/dictionary/crawl) defines the term **crawl** in the second sense:

> 2. to go very slowly or carefully.

Thus, you can use the term "crawl" with the preposition "towards", in order to show the direction. As in:

> - I crawled towards Computer Science

Comment: What does locomotion mean?

Comment: @Ooker: According to the Oxford Dictionary, locomotion means the movement or the ability to move from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

'Tread' carefully, tread is sometimes a slow word or means staying in place.

Also try 'slink' and 'shifted'.

'pivoted'

'trudged', 'mucked'
gradual, plodding, slack, creeping. inching along.

'about-face' is a change in direction in place. similar to shifted.

Comment: Hello, Nate. Please visit the Help Center for advice on how to give a good answer. Supporting evidence (with linked and attributed references where reasonable – here, dictionary definitions at the very least) is usually considered very important on ELU.